# How to get the Url string before & after "#" that works both in eClipse Development & in deployed real domain name in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Ok, I am deveoping a GWT app using eClipse,

Everytime I run my app in eClipse the it return this format of url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#!getOrder
```

Ok, if I deploy my app into a real domain then it will be like this `http://dm.com#!getOrder`

I have no ide of what this string `MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` in development mode for?

Currently I doing the `internationalization`. When typing `http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&locale=de#!getOrder`, it will show German version

But I don't want user to type `&locale=de` in the url by themselves, so I created a `listbox` in my header page and when user selects other language, for ex German, then the url should capture the url part before `#` & append `&locale=de` & then append the url part after `#`. If doing correctly it will be `http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&locale=de#!getOrder`

SO i tried `Window.Location.getHost()+"&locale=de"` then the url become `http://127.0.0.1:8888/myproject/&locale=de` which does not work in eclipse

So How to get the Url string before & after "#" that works both in eClipse Development & in deployed real domain name in GWT?

Answer (score 2):

That is because Window.Location.getHost() returns only the URL's host and port name.
Please try to use Window.Location.getHref() to get the entire URL, then you split, do the job and use Window.Location.assign(with the newURL).

Comment: we got a method to help us to do it properly, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do

```
String newUrl = Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setParameter("locale", "de").buildString();
```